# Tomcat Failover High Availability (active / passive)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tomcat, high-availability, failover

we have a jee web application running on apache tomcat , we need to deploy this application on production environment and we decided to use failover structure so we have one server active and another one passive and each of them contains tomcat server , what we need to know is how a to tell the passive server to handle coming requests when active server down or : how passive tomcat will run after active tomcat down ?
we are using windows server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using same windows server with two instances of Tomcat or two windows servers with one instance of Tomcat on each server?

Comment: I have two windows servers and two tomcat servers.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you can use windows built in failover functionality. Im not very familiar with it, but there are questions like:
[Windows Service automatic failover](https://serverfault.com/questions/219186/windows-service-automatic-failover)

But why do you want active/passive setup rather than two (or more) tomcats working simultaneously in a load balanced setup? IMO this is much better and possibly easier to configure.

Using tomcats session distribution any server can crash at will and no visitor notices any interruption.

You can also easily take one server out of the load balancer, perform work like upgrades, and then reenable it again.

Last but not least, when two servers are not enough to handle the load, you can add more, which i think is harder in a active/passive setup

(I would've just added a comment, since i dont really answer your question, but i lack points and I though I should give you this tip anyway :)

Comment: For this reason : http://serverfault.com/questions/462316/configure-windows-to-read-write-shared-san